# My minecraft skin wont load up in games

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've always have been in servers on HiveMC.com And then when i was playing a game of cowboys vs indians, my skin turned into a steve some
one please help!

Comment: Does it work now?

Answer (score 2):

Mojang skin servers may be down.

You can check on https://help.mojang.com/

Make sure all services say "This service is healthy. All is good!"

Otherwise, It might be a mod you are using or someone in your account changing your skin.

Answer (score 1):

as of now, you can't see your own skin, but you can see others. This is most likely due to Mojang doing the big switch to UUID (Unique User ID).